# Regex URL must be the format: http://host.domain/scriptname.extension, no query string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, url

URL must be of the form: http://host.domain/scriptname.extension, no query string.
ie, this is a valid URL: http://abc.axx.loc:8000/abcd.aspx.
I tried to do it like below, but it doesn't work well, anybody can help? thx.

```
var RegExp = /((h|H)(t|T)(t|T)(p|P)|(h|H)(t|T)(t|T)(p|P)(s|S)):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?\/\w+\.\w+$/;
```

Comment: You should give more condition of what is the requirements.

Comment: This is client validation, function is in js file.
in js:
function isValidURL(url) {
    if (url == "") {
        return false;
    }
    url == $.trim(url);   
    var RegExp = /((h|H)(t|T)(t|T)(p|P)|(h|H)(t|T)(t|T)(p|P)(s|S)):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?\/\w+\.\w+$/;

    if (RegExp.test(url)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

Comment: There are some examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var RegExp = /^https?\/\/[\w\-\.]+(:\d+)?\/[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+$/i;
```

Notice after the // the block [\w\-\.]+ is for the host and domain combination. It should match host.domain as well as host.subdomain1.subdomain2.domain etc.

The ^ and $ in the start and end is important so it matches the start and end of the string.

Also notice the use of \w\- because \w alone is not enough as it does not capture dashes.

Comment: No need to repeat each characters UPPER and lower, look `i` modifier.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is a valid url: http://abc.axx.loc:8000/abcd.aspx, but it can't pass.

Comment: Added support for abc.axx.loc - your primary example only had host.domain but I guess you want an arbitrary number of subdomains.

Comment: Thanks Yoni, I updated your answer to this and it works now, port is optional: var RegExp = /^https?:\/\/[\w\-\.]+(:[0-9]+)?\/[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+$/i;

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer. I would use \d instead of [0-9].

Comment: Thanks for the help Yoni! I'm sorry for the down vote, I just registered this account, I must clicked that by accident, and it does not allow me to vote up as it requires 15 reputation, sorry. Your answer is correct, I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, but try this out:

```
/http:\/\/(\w+)\.(\w+)\/(\w+)\.(\w+)/i
```

http://rubular.com/r/Vnoxj11cEC

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
var RegExp = /^https?:\/\/\w+\.\w+\/\w+\.\w+(:\d+)?$/i
```

That will valid an url case insensitive in `http` and `https` with the model you give.

The final `i` (it's named a modifier) do all the magic for case insensitive trick.

Comment: thanks, but when I add port, it doesn't work. like this URL: http://abc.axx.loc:8000/abcd.aspx

Comment: I'm not psychic, that's why I asked you to give _more details_... POST edited accordingly.

Comment: hi sputnick. would be nice if you remove your down vote from my answer..
As for your answer - the port regex is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

```
/((h|H)(t|T)(t|T)(p|P)|(h|H)(t|T)(t|T)(p|P)(s|S)):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?\/\w+\.\w+$/.test("http://abc.axx.loc:8000/abcd.aspx")
```

worksforme. However, some points:

- you should not name that variable `RegExp` - thats the constructor of JS regexes and should not be overwritten
- use a case-insensitive regex to get around that ugly `(h|H)`... scheme
- `\S+` matches all non-whitespace characters, which is nearly everything in a URL. This might allow the query strings you don't want.
- You seem to have forgotten the string start anchor

I'd suggest

```
/^https?:\/\/(\w+(:\w+)?@)?[\w.]+(:\d+)?\/\w+\.\w+$/i
```

or omit that part with the user-login and just allow `@` and `:` in the domain:

```
/^https?:\/\/[\w.:@]+\/\w+\.\w+$/i
```